# Change Coordinate System of a raster in ArcMap

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap

I have a problem with changing the coordinate system of a raster data set in ArcMap. The actual spatial reference of the Raster is specified as GCS_WGS_1984 in the Layer Properties. I want to change this into WGS_1984_Antarctic_Polar_Stereographic. I tried to do so in the Data Frame Properties. As a result my raster disappears and I can't even zoom to the Layer. When I try it with Geographic Coordinate System Transformations I can not select the wanted System. Maybe it is also important to tell, that when I load the Raster into ArcMap the following Error Message appears:

> one or more of the added layers has an extent that is not consistent
>   with the associated spatial reference information.

What can I do to change the Coordinate System?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is [Project Raster](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/project-raster.htm):

> Transforms a raster into a new projection.

Comment: Okay. Unfortunately I did not achieve to handle that so far. I got the same error message when trying project raster.

Comment: Make sure you change the coordinate system (projection) of the raster back to WGS 1984 first.